# Redundant to have index + full text on same column?

Tags: mysql, index

If I have a full text index is it redundant to have a regular index on the same column? I am asking this because I need to support 5.5 and 5.6 at the same time and am using a stored procedure to create the indexes and am wondering if I need both.

Answer (score 3):

Not redundant, but rarely practical.

An `INDEX` has limitations, based on 255 characters.  (There are too many wrinkles for me to go into detail.)

`FULLTEXT` is often used for big blocks of text.

Would you be looking at 'words' and doing = comparisons on the whole column?  Seems strange.

Here's one trick for when I want to search for a phrase that messes up in `FULLTEXT`.  Let's say I am looking for the title of your question, but I remember only 'index + full' (including the plus sign):

```
WHERE MATCH(col) AGAINST('+index +full')
  AND col LIKE '%index + full%'
```

The `MATCH` will quickly find only a few rows, but too many.  Then the `LIKE` finish filtering.  No plain `INDEX` is involved.